# Using ORDER to find specific OpportunityLineItem when the Oppty has duplicate OpportunityLineItems

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

How can I update an OpportunityLineItem's Quantity based on another OpportunityLineItem if the opportunity has duplicate OpportunityLineItems? How can I use ORDER in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing the direct question only, not other code issue or optimizations.

You already have the list filtered down to the product code via the query so using the product code as a map key effectively reduces the map to a single value as all records have that code

Simplify it down to:

1. Get a list of ProductA line items for the given opportunity

   ```
   Map<Id, OpportunityLineItem[]> oppsToProductA = New Map<Id,OpportunityLineItem[]>();
   for(OpportunityLineItem oil : [SELECT OpportunityId, Opportunity.Pricebook2Id, Name, ProductCode , PricebookEntryId, Quantity, UnitPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE ProductCode IN:lstProductCodes AND OpportunityId IN :LISTOFOPPIDSYOUAREWORKINGWITH]){
       OpportunityLineItem[] tmp = oppsToProductA.get(oli.OpportunityId);
       if(tmp == null) tmp = new OpportunityLineItem[]{};;
       tmp.add(oli);
       oppsToProductA.put(oli.OpportunityId,tmp);
   }
   ```
2. Build a list of Product B to insert

   ```
   for(Id oppId : oppsToProductA.keySet()){
       for(OpporutnityLineItem oliA : oppsToProductA.get(oppId)){
            oliList.add(new OpportunityLineItem(
                   OpportunityId = oppId, 
                   PricebookEntryId = pbeProduct2.Id,
                   Quantity = 1,
                   UnitPrice = oliA.UnitPrice * 0.05)
                 );
       }
   }
   ```

You will need to improve your code to handle the possibility that OpportunityLineItems across multiple Opportunities may be in context as the same time.